# Syntax for conditional one-way binding in ng-if expression in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know the syntax for one-way binding inside ng-if looks like this:

```
<div ng-if="::vm.user.loggedIn"></div>
```

(from [here](http://toddmotto.com/angular-one-time-binding-syntax/))

But what's the syntax if I want to use one-way binding with the not operator? I've tried something like

```
<div ng-if="!::vm.user.loggedIn"></div>
```

or

```
<div ng-if="::!vm.user.loggedIn"></div>
```

No luck. Any ideas?

Comment: I just tried, and `ng-if="::!vm.user.loggedIn"` works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/858tk3nn/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
<div ng-if="::(!vm.user.loggedIn)"></div>
```

Demo Plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZcV3yxTiERtPiPlMJb2L?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

It's not one-way binding, but one time binding that you are talking about. One time bindings only use the first value, and then never update.

However, `<div ng-if="::!vm.user.loggedIn"></div>` is completely valid and should work correctly. See this plunker for example: http://plnkr.co/edit/o1va21WuuAykFRTBOGRT?p=preview

The internal code angular uses doesn't do anything special to the expression, aside from stripping off the two colons at the start and changing a `oneTime` boolean. My guess is that you have some other logic (probably asynchronous) that determines `vm.user.loggedIn` and the 1 time binding uses the initial value, then does not update, or there is some other error preventing the code from working.

Comment: 1+ Because `ng-if="::!vm.user.loggedIn"` should work - https://jsfiddle.net/858tk3nn/